# How to check which Tab Bar item is active?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, uikit

I am trying to figure out how to check which tab bar button is active? Currently I have 5 to 6 different tab bar buttons, and want to check which one is active. Any input will be appreciated here.

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 17):

do you have UITabbar or UITabbarController?

if `UITabbar` then set tag for each item and then you see which item is selected using -

```swift
tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag
```

if `UITabbarController` then use

```swift
tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, but I did a different approach of using ViewWillDisappear and that did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

UITabBarController has a selectedViewController and a selectedIndex property. Here is the [UITabBarController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html%20%22%22)

Comment: Link is now dead, this is the correct link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html